# How can I make the div to float at the bottom without the box height changing everytime the window is resized?

Tags: html, css, forms, flexbox

I have developed a form. Here I want the "some text some text" section to stick at the bottom of the box and also I want the box to be of the same height as the screen. However the code that I have written does what I want but since I have manually added the height of the box as 87.2vh, everytime the browser window is resized the bottom part keeps moving up and down. How can I make it work?

This is my HTML code

```
<section id="about-work">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-body">
          <h4 class="title">Connect to My Email</h4>
          <!-- <p class="subtitle">Hello</p> -->
        <hr>
        <form method="post">
          <div class="input-group">
          <label class="label">My Email Address</label>
          <input class="input--style-4" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
        </div>
        <div class="box-btn">
          <a class="cta-btn align-middle" href="#">Take Control!</a>
        </div>
        </form>
      </div>
        <div class="box-bottom">
          <hr>
          <p class="form-bottom-txt">Some Text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>
```

This is my CSS code

```
#wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

#about-work {
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5fa;
  padding: 80px 0 0px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

#about-work .box {
  position: relative;
  height: 87.2vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 29px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#about-work .box-body{
  padding: 30px 55px 30px;
}

#about-work .title {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 1.25;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#about-work .input-group{
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px 0 22px 0;
}

#about-work .label {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #555;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#about-work input {
  outline: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
}

#about-work .input--style-4 {
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #fafafa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #666;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

#about-work .box-btn{
  /*margin-bottom: 10em;*/
}

#about-work .cta-btn {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #6a5b5b;;
  padding: 13px 30px 13px 30px;
  color: #6a5b5b;
}

#about-work .cta-btn:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(315deg, #aecad6 0%, #b8d3fe 74%);
  color: #6a5b5b; 
  border: 2px solid #aecad6;  
  box-shadow: 0 10px 29px 0 rgba(68, 88, 144, 0.1);  
}

#about-work .box-bottom{
  padding: 30px 55px 30px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1%;
}

#about-work .form-bottom-txt {
  font-size: 11px;
  line-height: 1.45;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 799px){
  #about-work{
    /*padding: 80px 0 0 0;*/
  }
  #about-work .box {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #about-work .title{
    font-size: 22px;
  }
  #about-work .label{
    font-size:16px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 799px) {
  #wrapper{
    background-color: #f5f5fa;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #about-work .box{
    max-width: 501px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a height to your html and body and replace vh with %:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

#about-work {
  height: 100%;
}

.#about-work .box {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```